# Django - TypeError - save() unexpected argument 'force_insert'

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Django app which works fine locally but I sent it to a Heroku server using postgres, everything loads fine from the database but if I try to register a new user with the following view:

```
def register(request, *args, **kwargs):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(*args, **kwargs)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
        return redirect('core:index')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForm()
return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

form:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Save method is implemented from django.contrib.auth

I get this error:

```
Django - TypeError - save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'
```

I read in a similar post about using *args and **kwargs within the view but that didn't make a difference, or, I didn't implement it correctly?

Edit: Unsure if this could be the cause but after a user is created this code gets implemented -

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(default='avatar.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    img = Image.open(self.image.path)

    if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
        output_size = (300, 300)
        img.thumbnail(output_size)
        img.save(self.image.path)
```

Through the use of:

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, *args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: show us your save method and your form

Comment: @iklinac Sorry about that, I've updated my original question

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but this may help someone else in the future.

The user app models.py has save() function, change it to:

def save(self, **kwargs):

https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/issues/15